# How add property at runtime to already existing class Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, runtime, reflection.emit

I'm trying to add a field to an existing class, I found a solution through Reflection.Emit, but this output only works if we define a new class, and I need to add it to an existing one, and I can't create an object of TypeBuilder type on an existing class to create it properties and attributes

```
var class_ = new MyClass();
var assemblyName = class_.GetType().Assembly.GetName();

AssemblyBuilder ab =
    AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(
        assemblyName,
        AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

ModuleBuilder mb =
    ab.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name);


TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType(
    "MyClass",
    TypeAttributes.Public);


AddProperty(tb, "testProp", "".GetType());

var class1 = new MyClass();
Console.WriteLine(class1.GetType().GetProperties().Length);
foreach (var item in class1.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Comment: That's not a common thing in C#. What problem are you trying to solve? Are you allowed to change the original class? For example: You could instead use a Dictionary, which gives you a dynamic set of Key-Value pairs rather than a fixed set of properties.

Comment: It would be so simple, I would use a dictionary, but I work with a framework to which I have to give a full-fledged class

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the requirements you are under?

Comment: Well, in short, there is a method that should return a list of objects of the "MyClass" type, which, for example, already has some field "Field1" and also in accordance with a data matrix of arbitrary sizes, both in length and in width, however, the output should always be a sheet of type MyClass

Comment: What is a "sheet"?

Comment: It mean list)))

Comment: So: Correct me if I am wrong - You have a third party library, that requires you to have a function `List<MyClass> MyFunction()` ? Is that correct so far?

Comment: Probably not, I need to return a list of MyClass type objects from the method, filled with arbitrary matrix sizes, it looks something like this
[[london, 1, 2],[paris,3,4]]
List<
MyClass{CountField, field1, field2, field3},
MyClass{CountField, field1, field2, field3}>
List<
MyClass{1, london, 1, 2},
MyClass{2, paris, 3, 4}>
Or another variation

[[london, 1, 2,two],[paris,3,4,one]]
List<
MyClass{CountField, field1, field2, field3},
MyClass{CountField, field1, field2, field3}>
List<
MyClass{1, london, 1, 2, two},
MyClass{2, paris, 3, 4, one}>

Comment: And they must be separate fields of the class, it cannot be a list in the class

Comment: Return _from what_? From where? I really do not get that notation. Is that maybe supposed to be JSON? Is `MyClass` a type from the library or a custom class?

Comment: return from method where I use reflection. This is custom class. I cannot use JSON